# Eloquent and Joins do not preserve model relationships

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-4, eloquent

There are 2 models `Product` and `Variant` where a `Product` hasMany `Variant` and a `Variant` belongsTo `Product`. Both models also contain many other relationships.

**Question:** How can you use Eloquent to select all Variants `->where('color','red')` and also its related `Product` must satisfy `->where('price', '>' '50')`? All the relationships of Variant in the returned resultset must be retained.

When a `join` is used on the Eloquent model, all relationships are lost except for the `products` which was joined. Eg: `$variant->product->id` works but not `$variant->someOtherModel->id`.

```
$variants =Variants::where('color', 'red')
    ->join('products', 'variants.product_id', '=', 'products.id')
    ->where('product.price', '>', 10)
    ->paginate(10);

foreach($variants as $variant) {
    echo $variant->product->id; //works
    echo $variant->someOtherModel->id;  // error, undefined function
}
```

How do you maintain all of `$variant`'s relationship?

---

Each `WHERE` clause appears to be chained using `OR` rather than `AND`! This is crazy!

```
$variants = Variant::where('color', 'red')
            ->with(array('Product' => function($query) {
               if(Input::get('price')     $query->where('price', '>', 10);
               if(Input::get('brand')     $query->where('brand', Input::get('brand'));
           }))
           ->paginate(10);
```

Answer (score 0):

Eager load constraints may solve it:

```
$Variants =Variants::where('color', 'red')
->with(array(
     'Product' => function($query) {
        $query->where('price', '>', 10);
     }
    ,'OtherModel'
    ,'FooBar'
))
->paginate(10);
```

Comment: If I tried using more `->where()` within the closure, the `WHERE` clauses appear to be chained using `OR` rather than `AND`. How can we force `AND` to be used? Updated original post with some more code.

Comment: try to add an advanced andWhere() query: http://laravel.com/docs/queries#advanced-wheres.
And can you print out the executed queries of the original and the new one?